# Aligning an image inside a div with CSS?

Tags: html, css

```
.framework {
    position: absolute;
}

.headerimg {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="framework">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="headerimg">
                <img src="Header.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is the code I've got and the `margin: 0 auto;` doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: "the margin: 0 auto; doesn't work" Yes, it does. It just doesn't happen to do what you want it to. That's why you should describe the problem in more detail and explain what you expect as a result so others can help. You should probably read the [how to ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `transform`to center horizontaly

```css
.framework {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.headerimg {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="framework">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="headerimg">
        <img src="Header.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to center things with margin auto you need to specify a width for the element you want to center and also set the parent elements width to 100%.

```
.framework {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
}

.headerimg {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:300px;
    display:block;
}
```